# Can't install keras or tensorflow in Windows 10 version - Anaconda

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

I have just had to reset Windows 10 to factory settings. I have re-installed Anaconda/Spyder and I am having problems installing Keras and TensorFlow at the moment.
I have attempted both pip and conda installations of TensorFlow but I am getting the below stack trace when I just attempt to run "import tensorflow as tf", or "import tf" (I wasn't sure which was correct)

To install tensorflow, I ran the below commands in the base Anaconda prompt as admin.

`conda create -n tf tensorflow`

`conda activate tf`

When I run the above import, I get the below error.

runfile('C:/Users/username/.spyder-py3/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/username/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\username.spyder-py3\untitled0.py", line 15, in 
import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

I have tried re-installing Anaconda, etc to no avail.

Anybody know what is wrong here?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please see the second part of [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) to understand how to connect Spyder to a conda environment.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions to install Tensorflow on Spyder

```
#Create environment
conda create -n tf python=3.7 anaconda
#Activate environment 
activate tf
#Install Spyder
conda install spyder
#Install Tensorflow
conda install tensorflow
#Test installation 
import tensorflow as tf
```